# Use node-XMLHttpRequest through a Proxy?

Tags: node.js, proxy, xmlhttprequest

I need to deploy my [node-XMLHttpRequest](https://github.com/driverdan/node-XMLHttpRequest) app to a server that uses a proxy to access the internet. In a terminal on that server, I can `curl -d "" http://website/path` and it works fine. I think `curl` recognizes the environment variable `http_proxy` in that case. The node app times out because it doesn't see the proxy. How can I get the node app to use the proxy?

For instance, could I use [http.globalAgent](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_globalagent) to send the requests through the proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fork adds a config object that can specify a proxy to use.

https://github.com/jbeuckm/node-XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Links are generally discouraged, would you mind posting any example cade that you have handy?

Answer (score 1):

Did you provide the proxy options to the http connection?

The below should help.

```
var http = require("http");

var options = {
hostname: "<proxy-server-address>",
port: <proxy-server-port>,
path: "http://www.xyz.com",
headers: {
  Host: "www.xyz.com"
         }
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res){ ... });

req.end();
```

Comment: Thanks - luckily `node-XmlHttpRequest` is based on `http` so I will be able to fork and modify the module to work through a proxy.