# Javascript - send singel http request from diffrent country

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, proxy, vpn

I need to send multi http requests. But, each request should be from diffrent country.  I thought to do it via vpn.
I did not find any javascript lib to send single http request via vpn..

Http requests from the backend - NodeJs
Is it possible?

Thank you!

Comment: From within the browser, node.js, or what environment? You're probably not going to succeed via VPN; maybe with a HTTP proxy provider, but even then you're severely restricted by cross-origin in the browser...

Comment: I plan to do it from the backed so NodeJs.. Edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From within node.js, you can make HTTP calls through HTTP proxies. Such proxies are available worldwide (free and commercial).

Here's how to do proxy requests: [Use node-XMLHttpRequest through a Proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22844839/use-node-xmlhttprequest-through-a-proxy)

Another option is to use commercial services which provide this as service, such as https://wonderproxy.com/ (I'm not affiliated i any way).