# REST Call with node js: "Error: connect ETIMEDOUT" and "http code 0"

Tags: node.js, http, request, postman

I set up a REST Server and I can send http requests via Postman.
That works fine.
Now I am trying to send a GET request from this server to another server.

Let me show you:

```
const express = require('express');
const XMLHttpRequest = require('xmlhttprequest').XMLHttpRequest;
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    const http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
    // Postman Mock
    //const url = '...';
    http.open("GET", url);
    http.send();

    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        console.log(this.readyState, this.status);
        console.log(this.statusText);
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
            console.log("It worked!");
            console.log(http.responseText);
        }
    }

    res.status(200).json({
        message: 'Handling GET requests to /product'
    });
});
module.exports = router;
```

I send a GET request via Postman to my server and that should trigger another GET request from my server to the [jsonplacholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/).
But I get this:

*4 0*

*Error: connect ETIMEDOUT ...
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1128:14) {
errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '...',
port: ...
}*

There is no HTTP Code 0 ...
Besides I tried this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>The XMLHttpRequest Object</h2>


<script>
    const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const url='https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
    Http.open("GET", url);
    Http.send();

    Http.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
        console.log("TEST");
        console.log(Http.readyState, Http.status);
        console.log(Http.responseText)
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

In the Browser Console you can see this:
TEST
2 200
TEST
3 200
... an the extreme long json coming from jsonplaceholder

So it worked fine here.
What am I doing wrong? And is it even possible to send a request like I tried it?

Thanks for your help! :)

Marc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works just fine. It seems like you have a proxy blocking the request. You can look at this thread for adding the proxy using xmlHttpRequest [Use node-XMLHttpRequest through a Proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22844839/use-node-xmlhttprequest-through-a-proxy).

I would recommend you use a higher level http request library like superagent https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent

Comment: Thanks man! I tried it in another network and it worked. :) I will check out the Proxy thread and the superagent lib. Thank you very much!